# Prevent console.log() from posting beside REPL prompt in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently my console.log() stream prints beside the REPL prompt, resulting in a undesirable effect:

```
> example!
```

when the desired effect is only "example!" without the REPL prompt ">".
Is there a way to **separate** the REPL prompt from the console.log() stream?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by printing beside the REPL prompt? What exact command did you type in to the REPL?

Comment: Let's say we have the prompt ">" and have a console.log("hello World!") in the program. When the REPL prints the prompt ">", so will the console.log() - leading to "> hello World!" instead of the expected "hello World! <newline> >".